Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions.
Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Prove that the set $\{x \in X : f(x) < g(x) \}$ is open.
If we equip $\mathbb{R}$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, then the result follows immediately. Because, if we define $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$, then $h(x)$ is continuous. Then, $h^{-1}((0,\infty))$ would be open because of the continuity of $h$ and we are done. I believe these calculations would work for any metric with $d(x,y) = \lVert x-y \rVert$ on $\mathbb{R}$, where $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is a norm.
What I am asking is that if the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary, is it still possible to show the given set is open?

You used two facts: that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so is $f - g$, and that $(0, \infty)$ is open. Can you find a metric where at least one of these is false?

all you need is @mihaild hint which is what I was going to say.


What I am asking is that if the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary, is it still possible to show the given set is open?

No, it does not have to be open. Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ as set and $f(x)=x$ while $g(x)=0$. Then
$$\{x\in X: f(x)<g(x)\}=(-\infty,0)$$
Now pick any metric on $\mathbb{R}$ such that this interval is not open. Such metric exists, it arises from any bijection $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $h((-\infty,0))=(-\infty,0]$ by transfering the Euclidean metric from range to domain.
Put that metric on both sides, so that $f$ is continuous. $g$ is of course always continuous as a constant function. And we are done.
